# how to fix 401 Unauthorised, jwt authentication

Tags: kotlin, authentication, jwt, ktor

Hi I am implementing JWT authentication in my ktor project. When I login, i get a JWT token, when I use the same token for another API call I get `401 Unauthorised`.

When login request is called, I generate a token using `generateToken` function

```
class JwtService {

    private val issuer = "testServer"
    private val jwtSecretTest = System.getenv("JWT_SECRET_TEST")
    private val algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(jwtSecretTest)

    val verifier: JWTVerifier = JWT
        .require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer(issuer)
        .build()

    fun generateToken(user: User): String {
        return JWT.create()
            .withSubject("TestAuthentication")
            .withIssuer(issuer)
            .withClaim("email", user.email)
            .sign(algorithm)
    }
}
```

Application.kt

```
 val jwtService = JwtService()

install(Authentication) {
    jwt ("jwt") {
        verifier(jwtService.verifier)
        realm = "Test Server"
        validate {
            val payload = it.payload
            val email = payload.getClaim("email").toString()
            val user = db.findUserByEmail(email)
            user
        }
    }
}
```

When i call DailySalesReportCreateRoute from postman, I get `401 Unauthorised`

```
fun Route.dailySalesReportRoutes(
    db: Repo,
    jwtService: JwtService,
    hashFunction: (String) -> String
) {
    authenticate("jwt") {
        post<DailySalesReportCreateRoute> {
            val dailySalesReport = try {
                call.receive<DailySalesReport>()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, SimpleResponse(false, "Missing fields"))
                return@post
            }

            try {
                //val email = call.principal<User>()!!.email
                //db.addDailySalesReport(dailySalesReport, email)
                dailySalesReport.loggedInUserEmail.let { it1 -> db.addDailySalesReport(dailySalesReport, it1) }
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, SimpleResponse(true, "Note added successfully"))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, SimpleResponse(false, e.message ?: "Some problem occurred"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thanks
R

Comment: How exactly do you send a JWT via Postman?

Comment: Hello @AlekseiTirman thank you for responding, in postman, Authorization tab -> type - Bearer token -> token - i put the token. Then I send the request

Comment: check if you are able to find right user by email or jwt returning right email

Comment: hi, if the response in 401 Unauthorised, how can see what is JWT returning, could you let me know how can I check this please

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to add

```kotlin
.withExpiresAt()
```

for example:

```kotlin
fun generateToken(user: User): String {
        return JWT.create()
            .withSubject("TestAuthentication")
            .withIssuer(issuer)
            .withClaim("email", user.email)
            .withExpiresAt(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 600000000))
            .sign(algorithm)
    }
```

it can also be a problem if you didn't fill in `.withAudience(audience)`

I would also like to recommend that you put a breakpoint in the token verifier `com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier#verifyClaims` to understand on which claim the validation error occurs. I think the code inside is not very difficult to understand.

Comment: thank you for responding, will check that and get back thank you

Comment: i have checked the verifyClaims method and the case it executed was `PublicClaims.NOT_BEFORE`

Comment: can you please attach the token that your application generates?